# How to convert canvas.toblob() callback to an Observable

Tags: javascript, callback, rxjs, observable

I want to create a function that return an observable of file

My current working code uses a promise

```js
testPromise(): Promise<File> {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 600;

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 800, 600);

    canvas.toBlob((blob: Blob) => resolve(new File([blob], name)), type, quality);
  });
}
```

Instead of that, I want to return `Observable<File>`

I tried the following but I cannot pass the `toBlob()` arguments such as `type` and `quality`

```js
testObservable(): Observable<File> {

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 800;
  canvas.height = 600;

  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 800, 600);

  const toBlob = bindCallback(canvas.toBlob);

  return toBlob().pipe(
    map((blob: Blob) => {
      return new File([blob], name)
    })
  );
}
```

**Expected behavior**

```
const toBlob = bindCallback(canvas.toBlob);
toBlob(type, quality) // <= Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.
```

Here I get an error on **toBlob** `Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.`

**Current behavior**

```
const toBlob = bindCallback(canvas.toBlob);
toBlob() // <= No type or quality arguments
```

Here is the canvas.toBlob interface according to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)

> void canvas.toBlob(callback, mimeType, qualityArgument);

***PS***: I don't want to convert the Promise to an Observable,but I need to convert the callback directly to an Observable

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid `bindCallback` is not a good choice here because it expects the callback to be the last argument and not the first as what `toBlob` expects.

I think you'll have to wrap this call with na Observable yourself:

```
return new Observable(observer => {
  canvas.toBlob(result => {
    observer.next(result);
    observer.complete();
  }, type, quality);
});
```